# How to run a single testcase in gradle 2.x (with JUnit)?

Tags: testing, gradle

I am using Gradle 2 and I want to run a single testcase from the terminal.

I found some information about this and it seems that since gradle 1.10 a `--test` option has been added. More info here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/193

However I am trying with Gradle 2 and it doesn't seem to work.

```
ezio_auditore@blackflag:~/workspace/justHibernate$ gradle --tests *Dummy*.stupidTest test

Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

I also tried to put `#` and `.` as a separator between class name and testcase name, as described at https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2865, but no luck.

Is it possible to run a single testcase with Gradle 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--tests` is a command-line option specific to the `test` task, and has to come immediately after `test`. Depending on your shell, you may also have to quote the test name pattern. Try:

```
gradle test --tests '*Dummy*.stupidTest'
```